# Is amazon's AWS Textract supported on sdk for browser (in javascript)?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

This is the src for AWS JS SDK i am using:

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.487.0.min.js"></script>
```

[Latest SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/) can be found here.

After setting up cognito identity in aws and adding aws credentials to the js code.
When i wrote this code:

```
var textract = new AWS.Textract();
```

It shows this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: AWS.Textract is not a constructor

When i checked the release notes for that particular sdk version - [SDK-release notes](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/release-aws-sdk-for-javascript-v2-4-8/?tag=releasenotes%23keywords%23javascript),in list for browser support, it did'nt mention Textract.

But there is still a Javascript documentation for it:
[AWS Textract](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Textract.html)

AWS object contents:

```
Object
ACM: ƒ ()
APIGateway: ƒ ()
ApplicationAutoScaling: ƒ ()
AutoScaling: ƒ ()
CUR: ƒ ()
ChainableTemporaryCredentials: ƒ (e)
CloudFormation: ƒ ()
CloudFront: ƒ ()
CloudHSM: ƒ ()
CloudTrail: ƒ ()
CloudWatch: ƒ ()
CloudWatchEvents: ƒ ()
CloudWatchLogs: ƒ ()
CodeBuild: ƒ ()
CodeCommit: ƒ ()
CodeDeploy: ƒ ()
CodePipeline: ƒ ()
CognitoIdentity: ƒ ()
CognitoIdentityCredentials: ƒ (e,t)
CognitoIdentityServiceProvider: ƒ ()
CognitoSync: ƒ ()
Comprehend: ƒ ()
ComprehendMedical: ƒ ()
Config: ƒ (e)
ConfigService: ƒ ()
CostExplorer: ƒ ()
CredentialProviderChain: ƒ (e)
Credentials: ƒ ()
DeviceFarm: ƒ ()
DirectConnect: ƒ ()
DynamoDB: ƒ ()
DynamoDBStreams: ƒ ()
EC2: ƒ ()
ECR: ƒ ()
ECS: ƒ ()
EFS: ƒ ()
ELB: ƒ ()
ELBv2: ƒ ()
EMR: ƒ ()
ElastiCache: ƒ ()
ElasticBeanstalk: ƒ ()
ElasticTranscoder: ƒ ()
Endpoint: ƒ (e,t)
EndpointCache: ƒ e(e)
EventListeners: {Core: constructor, CorePost: constructor, Logger: constructor, Json: constructor, Rest: constructor, …}
Firehose: ƒ ()
GameLift: ƒ ()
HttpClient: ƒ ()
HttpRequest: ƒ (e,t)
HttpResponse: ƒ ()
IAM: ƒ ()
Inspector: ƒ ()
Iot: ƒ ()
IotData: ƒ ()
JSON: {Builder: ƒ, Parser: ƒ}
KMS: ƒ ()
Kinesis: ƒ ()
KinesisVideo: ƒ ()
KinesisVideoArchivedMedia: ƒ ()
KinesisVideoMedia: ƒ ()
Lambda: ƒ ()
LexModelBuildingService: ƒ ()
LexRuntime: ƒ ()
MTurk: ƒ ()
MachineLearning: ƒ ()
MarketplaceCommerceAnalytics: ƒ ()
MediaStoreData: ƒ ()
MobileAnalytics: ƒ ()
Model: {Api: ƒ, Operation: ƒ, Shape: ƒ, Paginator: ƒ, ResourceWaiter: ƒ}
OpsWorks: ƒ ()
ParamValidator: ƒ (e)
Personalize: ƒ ()
PersonalizeEvents: ƒ ()
PersonalizeRuntime: ƒ ()
Polly: ƒ ()
Pricing: ƒ ()
Protocol: {Json: {…}, Query: {…}, Rest: {…}, RestJson: {…}, RestXml: {…}}
RDS: ƒ ()
Redshift: ƒ ()
Rekognition: ƒ ()
Request: ƒ (e,t,r)
ResourceGroups: ƒ ()
ResourceWaiter: ƒ (e,t)
Response: ƒ (e)
Route53: ƒ ()
Route53Domains: ƒ ()
S3: ƒ ()
SAMLCredentials: ƒ (e)
SES: ƒ ()
SNS: ƒ ()
SQS: ƒ ()
SSM: ƒ ()
STS: ƒ ()
SecretsManager: ƒ ()
SequentialExecutor: ƒ ()
Service: ƒ (e)
ServiceCatalog: ƒ ()
Signers: {RequestSigner: ƒ, V2: ƒ, V3: ƒ, V3Https: ƒ, V4: ƒ, …}
StorageGateway: ƒ ()
TemporaryCredentials: ƒ (e,t)
Translate: ƒ ()
VERSION: "2.487.0"
WAF: ƒ ()
WebIdentityCredentials: ƒ (e,t)
WorkDocs: ƒ ()
XHRClient: ƒ ()
XML: {Builder: ƒ, Parser: ƒ}
apiLoader: ƒ i(e,t)
```

Is there something i am missing? or is there a other way around to use it in browser?

Any help or approach will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you `console.log` the contents of the `AWS` object?

Comment: @DimitarTsonev it doesn't mention Textract. Check the log above.

Comment: Hmm, the package installed from `npm` contains the `Textract` functionality. I am not sure why the CDN version doesn't have it.

Comment: yes, i know, any work around possible?

Comment: why are you using t he CDN version ?

Comment: i don't use npm currently.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue using npm specifically, the Textract class is contained within "aws-sdk/clients/textract"

```js
const Textract = require("aws-sdk/clients/textract");
```

(I know this isn't exactly the question, but when I searched this question, this page came up, hoping I was able to answer this question for people using npm)